# Extremely slow MyISAM slave updates

Tags: mysql, myisam, update

I have 2 slaves where one is working as expected, but the other slave is extremely slow when executing `update` statements. The `insert` and `delete` statements are fast.

I used the command `check table tbl_name` to see if any MyISAM table was corrupt. Both the slaves are MyISAM only.

I am using (AWS ec2 instance) ext3 for the fast slave and xfs for the the other. Is that the reason why the updates are taking time?

Comment: You are at the mercy of what AWS thinks is a good config for your part of a computer.  Post more details; maybe there is something that can be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare both slaves performance using Percona utilities mentioned below:

- [pt-heartbeat](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-heartbeat.html) measures replication lag on a MySQL server. You can use it to update a master or monitor a replica. If possible, MySQL connection options are read from your .my.cnf file.
- [pt-table-checksum](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-table-checksum.html) performs an online replication consistency check by executing checksum queries on the master, which produces different results on replicas that are inconsistent with the master.